# Duda consulta SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql

Tengo dudas a la hora de realizar una consulta en Oracle SQL Developer. Tengo 2 tablas. Una con Emisores(Emisor_ID, Nombre, etc) y otra con Transacciones que realizan esos emisores(Emisor_ID, fechacreacion, documento, etc). En la tabla de Transacciones se graba un registro por cada transacción. Quería sacar una consulta con las cantidad de transacciones agrupadas por emisor, así como el porcentaje de que representa la cantidad de transacciones del emisor respecto al total. Y es en este punto donde tengo problemas. Saco la cantidad de transacciones agrupadadas por emisor y también la suma total de todas las transacciones pero no se como sacar el porcentaje.

La query que tengo de momento es:

```
Select
    c.emisor_id,
    c.nombre,
    count(*) as Cantidad,
    (select distinct 
        count(*)
    from transacciones
    where fechacreacion > sysdate -10) as Total
From transaccciones n inner join emisor_id c
on c.emisor_id=n.emisor_id
where n.fechacreacion > sysdate -10
group by c.emisor_id, c.nombre
order by Cantidad desc
```

Con esto me mostraria todo menos la columna del porcentaje.

Gracias y un saludo de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu código esté correcto, tendrías que dividir  transacciones del emisor entre el total de transacciones y eso lo multiplicas por 100. Creo que sería algo así:

```
Select
    c.emisor_id,
    c.nombre,
    count(*) as Cantidad,
    (select distinct 
        count(*)
    from transacciones
    where fechacreacion > sysdate -10) as Total,
    ((select distinct 
        count(*)
    from transacciones
    where fechacreacion > sysdate -10) / 
    count(*) as Cantidad)*100 as Porcentaje
From transaccciones n inner join emisor_id c
on c.emisor_id=n.emisor_id
where n.fechacreacion > sysdate -10
group by c.emisor_id, c.nombre
order by Cantidad desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
c.emisor_id,
c.nombre,
COUNT(n.emisor_id) AS 'Cantidad de facturas',
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaccciones WHERE fechacreacion > sysdate -10) / COUNT(n.emisor_id)) * 100 AS 'Porcentaje'
FROM emisor_id n 
LEFT JOIN transaccciones c ON c.emisor_id = n.emisor_id
where n.fechacreacion > sysdate -10
group by c.emisor_id, c.nombre
order by Cantidad desc
```

Podrías hacer un `LEFT JOIN` y luego contar sobre los id de la tabla `transaccciones`, después solo cuentas el total de facturas, divides entre los id de `transaccciones` que tengas y multiplicas por 100. Espero te sirva saludos.